# LXML: Cannot import etree

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, python-import

I went to this page and downloaded the tar file : `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3.4#downloads`

I then copied the lxml folder to my Python26/Lib folder. Now, when i go to the interpreter and type `from lxml import etree` i get the error: `cannot import etree`. Does someone know what is going wrong?  I am running windows.

Answer (score 3):

Better follow the [installation instructions](http://lxml.de/installation.html); lxml has some C components that require compilation.

I am guessing that you are on Windows, in which case the [binary egg](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#where-are-the-binary-builds) should work. On PyPI, the most recent version to include binary eggs for Windows is [2.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3), but you can find [more recent (unofficial) installers elsewhere](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Answer (score 3):

Simply unzipping the archive and moving it is not how one should install Python packages. You usually run `python setup.py install` from the folder; but on Windows there are easier ways.

Go to [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) download and the installer for the version of Python you are using.